# React Native Gradient Button Issue

Tags: react-native, expo, linear-gradients

I'm trying to create a gradient button using expo-linear gradient, I'm trying to achieve the effect similar to below image
[click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixXjm.png)

Can anyone help me?

So far I Have done the following with the expo-linear-gradient library.

```
   <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
      <LinearGradient
        colors={[disableLightColor, disabledColor]}
        start={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
        end={{ x: 0, y: 1 }}
        style={{ ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject }}
      />
      <View style={styles.overlay}></View>
      <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Button 2</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

Styles

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-around'
  },
  button: {
    padding: 6,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flex: 1,
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.3,
    shadowRadius: 2,
    elevation: 3, 
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  glossyButton: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)',
    borderBottomWidth: 0,
    shadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)',
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 4 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.8,
    shadowRadius: 5,
    elevation: 2,
  },
  safeArea: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#000',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    borderColor: '#951e36', // Set the border color to red (you can change this to your desired color)
    borderWidth: 4, // Set the border width
  },
  overlay: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    height: '70%', // Adjust this value as needed for the size of the white overlay
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)',
  },
});
```